# Book on Volume Shadow Copy Service API

Tags: volume-shadow-service

I'm having trouble finding books on the Windows Volume Shadow Copy Service. Can anyone point me to a good book on the subject. I'm looking at the API from the point of view to write a VSS requestor.

Comment: I don't know of any books that cover it, but I thought the MSDN documentation was quite good.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa384961

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this concludes then that there is no such book.